# How to get the ID of record in another html?

Tags: django

why i cant get the ID of payment type, even i already print the ID in the html?

in my first html (elementary.html) I have this code

```
<select name="gradelevel" id="gradelevel" onchange="ChangeYearList(this.value)">
    <option">-- Education Level --</option>
    {% for ylvl in edulevel %}
    <option value="{{ylvl.id}}">{{ylvl.Description}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>

<div id="txtHint" class="scale-in-center" width="100%"></div>


<script>
function ChangeYearList(str) {
var xhttp;
var x = document.getElementById("gradelevel").value;
if (str == "") {
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
return;
}
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "{% url 'paymentElementary' %}?payments_ID="+str, true);
xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

this is my views.py

```
def paymentElementary(request):

paymentsid = request.GET.get('payments_ID')
payment = ScheduleOfPayment.objects.filter(Education_Levels=paymentsid).order_by('Payment_Type').distinct('Payment_Type')
return render(request, 'accounts/paymentElementary.html', {"payment":payment})
```

This is my second html (paymentElementary.html)

```
<select id="payments" name ="payments">
    <option value="0">-- Payment Type --</option>
   {% for paymentschedule in payment %}
    <option value="{{paymentschedule.Payment_Type.id}}">{{paymentschedule.Payment_Type.id}}. {{paymentschedule.Payment_Type}}</option>
    {% endfor%}
</select>
```

this is what it looks like in web view

[image]

it works like a charm. but when i tried to save it into my database

```
id = request.POST.get('payments')
payment = PaymentType(id=id)

V_insert_data = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.create(
    Payment_Type=payment
        )
```

this is the error

[image]

this is the full traceback

[image]

Comment: Can you provide `payment` object value

Comment: it works fine when i provide payment value """ paymentelem = PaymentType(id=1) """"

Comment: Write this `print(vars(payment))` before render process in view.py. Provide that printed value of `payment`

Comment: it prints 'None'

Comment: that means when you passed `paymentsid` it's not present in database thus you stuck in this problem. solution is that 1) pass `paymentsid` which present in database. 2) in html file add if condition, If value is not None then for iterate value using for loop. 3) use ModeName.objects.get() instead of ModelName.objects.filter().

Comment: can you show me your solutions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214708/discussion-between-justin-and-ashish-sondagar).

Answer (score 0):

- update view.py file in this way

```
def paymentElementary(request):

paymentsid = request.GET.get('payments_ID')
payment = ScheduleOfPayment.objects.get(Education_Levels=paymentsid).order_by('Payment_Type').distinct('Payment_Type')
return render(request, 'accounts/paymentElementary.html', {"payment":payment})
```

Comment: when itry your answer the paymenttype didnt show in my html,

Comment: Make sure which condition you pass in ORM query That kind of data exist in database.

Comment: it perfectly works when i use filter than get, my concern is why i didnt get the ID of payment type when i tried to save it in my database,

Comment: debug your ORM query. write `payment = ScheduleOfPayment.objects.get(Education_Levels=paymentsid).order_by('Payment_Type')` instead of `payment = ScheduleOfPayment.objects.get(Education_Levels=paymentsid).order_by('Payment_Type').distinct('Payment_Type')`. print values of `payment`. Make sure you passed `paymentsid` it's present in database.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with my "" payment = ScheduleOfPayment.objects.filter(Education_Levels=paymentsid).order_by('Payment_Type').distinct('Payment_Type') because i already print the ID in the html, (look at the picture), my problem is i didnt get the ID, always none

Comment: use this `V_insert_data = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.create(**payment)`

Comment: **payment? like this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214681/discussion-between-justin-and-ashish-sondagar).